# Unbind events from jQuery handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to work around an old system and essentially hijack a submit button under some condition, apply a handler to it, and then unbind this handler when I'm done. I am using `bind` and `unbind` but the event is being bound cumulatively each time I launch the form in question.

```
class MyForm(){
    constructor(){
        // button in question
        this.$submit = $('#submit');

        this.$submit.bind('click', this.submit.bind(this));
        return this;
    }

    submit(){
        return this.doAjaxStuff();
    }

    doAjaxStuff(){
         var self = this;
         return $.post(file, data).always(function(){
              self.$submit.unbind('click', self.submit);
         });
    }
}
```

Unfortunately every time I create a new `MyForm` the event is bound again but never unbound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple fix is use `off()` first and namespace your event. Removing a namespaced event won't interfere with other listeners of same event

```
this.$submit.off('click.special').on('click.special', this.submit.bind(this));
```

Note that `bind()` and `unbind()` are deprecated .. use `on()` and `off(0` instead.

A better approach would be delegate this once on page load and not keep calling the same class

Comment: I specifically need `off` to only be called for the handler I defined `(this.submit)`.  I am working around bad code on a time sensitive project, and this is the only solution I can think of. I know it can work, I just don't know why my method is not working.

Comment: You can also namespace events...but best would be delegate this once only on page load

Comment: Try `this.$submit.off('click.special').on('click.special', this.submit.bind(this));`